# Can all dragons breathe fire?

Tags: dragonlance

In most Dragonlance books (Chronoicles+Legends), dragon breath attacks are classified per color/metal. Alhough confusing, especially with metallic dragons and their dual weapon, it makes sense.

However, in The Legend Of Huma (by Richard Knaak), the silver dragon

> Gwyneth

appears to be able to breathe fire. Moreover, she says that any dragon can breathe fire, but it is very taxing on stamina.

Do silver dragons breathe fire? Or is it an inconsistency with the TSR canon?

Comment: You may want to ask this question in the RPG stackexchnge.  Granted it is not as populated as sci-fi and fantasy, but you will still be able to get some good answers there.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103834/can-all-dragonlance-dragons-breathe-fire - here you are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It is an inconsistency

According to the [Dragonlance Nexus](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Dragon), dragons use breath weapons as follows:

### Chromatic (evil) dragons:

- red - fire
- blue - lightning
- green - chlorine gas
- black - acid
- white - cold

### Metallic (good) dragons:

- brass: heat wave/sleep gas
- bronze: lighting/repulsive gas
- copper: acid/gas of slowness
- silver: cone of cold/paralyzing gas
- gold: cone of fire/chlorine gas

Dragonlance Nexus attributes [the odd description of that particular dragon](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Heart_(Silver_Dragon)) as an inconsistency:

> It has been noted that Heart breathed fire on Crynus to destroy him, but silver dragons can not breath fire. Most likely this was cold instead.

---

Another possibility, as noted [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103834/can-all-dragonlance-dragons-breathe-fire) (in the comments):

The Dragon could have used fire as a magic spell, not as a breath weapon. Hence the exhaustion typical for all spellcasters after using their spells.

Comment: Are you sure gold dragons don’t have weakening breath as their second breath weapon?

Comment: No, gold dragons have fire or poison gas.  The reason is the golds predate the other metallic dragon types, going back to original D&D, whereas the other good dragon types originated in first edition AD&D.  So golds don't follow the same pattern as other metallic dragons.

Comment: @Buzz - They have weakening gas in modern D&D. Are you saying that gold dragons in Dragonlance are from an older D&D version than the others?

Comment: @Adamant DRAGONLance used the AD&D rules in existence at the time it was created (first edition AD&D).  It was updated for second edition, which did not change the dragon breath weapons significantly; then it was spun off as a separate game:  Dragon Dice.  TSR (having turned down Magic:  The Gathering) thought they could created a "collectable dice game" in that universe.  *Dragons of Summer Flame* was published at the same time as the dice game, making changes to the world to fit the new game rules.  But, given dragons' importance to the setting, their breath weapons are frozen in the 1980s.

Comment: @Buzz I agree, as the majority of the books were written in the 80's, the authors probably decided to stick to the older rule set to avoid inconsistencies. But still there are quite a few inconsistencies in the books, especially between books of different authors.